# Registration with email, password combination gives me the error: Error: Illegal arguments: string, undefined, off

Tags: reactjs, react-native, express, react-hooks

I have a login mask where the user has to enter email and password. It is then checked whether this user exists or whether his password matches. When I run the following code on my local machine, I get the bcrypt error shown below. The access_token cookie is also not set. My server runs in local mode on port 3000, my frontend on 8800. I host the whole thing in a cloud server (HEROKU). Everything works.

```
import User from "../models/User.js";
import bcrypt from "bcryptjs";
import { createError } from "../error.js";
import jwt from "jsonwebtoken";

export const signin = async (req, res, next) => {
try {
const user = await User.findOne({ email: req.body.email });
if (!user) return next(createError(404, "User wurde nicht gefunden!"));

const isCorrect = bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, user.password);   
if (!isCorrect) return next(createError(400, "Falsches Passwort"));

const token = jwt.sign({ id: user._id }, process.env.JWT);
const { password, ...others } = user._doc;

return res
  .cookie("access_token", token, {
    httpOnly: true,
    maxAge: 7200000,
  })
  .status(200)
  .json(others);
 } catch (err) {
   next(err);
 }
};
```

> bcrypt.js:286
> nextTick(callback.bind(this, Error("Illegal arguments: "+(typeof s)+',
> '+(typeof hash))));
> ^
>
> Error: Illegal arguments: string, undefined

Comment: what arguments are you passing to bcrypt.compare() ? The first argument should be your password in plain text and the second one should be the generated hash. you also need to await for  bcrypt.compare()

Comment: looks like `user.password` is `undefined`. You can try `user._doc.password` instead